# "Pregnant" as a taboo word

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, offensive-language

This recent article from [The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/fabulous/7832143/the-queen-word-pregnant-vulgar-different-term/) states that the term pregnant, in this specific case referred to Meghan Markle, is considered vulgar by the Queen.

> According to a recently-resurfaced Us Weekly feature, the term is one of Her Majesty's pet peeves.
>
> The piece - which was published back when Prince George was a baby - ***quotes a Palace source as saying she finds it "vulgar".***
>
> So, what will the 92-year-old be calling mum-to-be Meghan?
>
> The article states that she'll be telling people she's "in the family way".

Apart from the Queen's personal preferences,   I found that the term [pregnant](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pregnant#etymonline_v_19407):

> Retained its status as a taboo word until c. 1950. (Etymonline)

from which, probably, its perceived "vulgarity”.

The above statement apprears to be confirmed also by the following article from ***[tv.avclub.com](https://tv.avclub.com/more-than-60-years-ago-a-pregnant-lucille-ball-couldn-1798239435)***:

> ***More than 60 years ago, a pregnant Lucille Ball couldn’t call herself “pregnant”***.
>
> - *The script for “Lucy Is Enceinte” famously had to dance around saying **the word “pregnant,” a term CBS deemed too vulgar for air.”***

Questions:

- why was the term considered vulgar?
- and what more commonly accepted expressions were used to refer to someone who was "pregnant” in the '50s.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86344/discussion-on-question-by-user240918-pregnant-as-a-taboo-word).

Comment: @BobJarvis et al.: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
answer,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: **Unfortunately, it is not technically practical for moderators to perform more than one migration from the comment thread to the chatroom. So further discussion here will simply be deleted.**

Answer (score 46):

I would guess that the word "pregnant" focuses on the state of the woman's body whereas a euphemism focuses (or at least pretends to focus) on the anticipation of a child.

Referencing a bodily state or function typically is taboo or disfavored.

Comment: I think you are on to something. You might post some meterial to support your impressions.

Comment: Furthermore; in this case, the speaker (i.e., the Queen) wouldn't even be referring to herself, but would instead be discussing the state of *another person's* body, which could VERY easily be considered inappropriate.

Comment: *WHY* is referencing a bodily state or function typically taboo or disfavored.

Comment: @Mazura because humans are ashamed of their physical forms... read Genesis... :)

Comment: @Mazura some people have an aversion to any discussion about matters that they would regard as *private* and *personal*, and use euphemisms to avoid the direct mention of the matter. Hence the myriad of euphemisms for anything related to excretory functions. But even discussing something as minor as a runny nose or itchy scalp would in some circles be *unseemly*.

Comment: @Carly or is the shame more concentrated amongst those that have *read* one of the monotheistic texts? ;-)

Comment: @Chappo now you're thinking with portals :)

Comment: @Carly "God created us in His image... How embarrassing!"

Comment: @Mazura Taboo? - simply because they said so.

Comment: @Kapten-N: Note, they weren't ashamed of their made-in-God's-image forms when he made them. That didn't happen till they ate the fruit he told them not to eat.

Comment: only when they gained an awareness of their Being did they seek to 'protect' it... for how could one seek to conceal that which is already concealed in the mind (by benevolent ignorance, perhaps)?

Comment: @Mazura because, with one notable exception, it implies that she had s...e...x

Comment: @LarsH So basically, wisdom makes you realize that God has an embarrassing body?

Comment: @Kapten-N: This isn't the place for an extended discussion, but no. Taking knowledge that God says you're not ready for leads you into all sorts of major problems (like death), of which shame about being naked is one. (God doesn't have a body, BTW... https://www.gotquestions.org/God-physical-body.html)

Comment: This makes sense; we have a number of euphemisms for pregnant - “what’s your due date”, “I’m expecting” - all focusing on the end product of the pregnancy

Comment: @LarsH I don't know how to move comments to chat. I'll leave that for the moderators. - So, we were supposedly created in God's image, but God has no body?

Comment: @Kapten-N: (I should amend what I said above by saying that God didn't have a body at the time of creation of humans; but since incarnation, he now has a human body.) Being made in the image of God is understood as referring to having rationality, moral capacity, creativity... in distinction to the other creatures God made. (https://www.gotquestions.org/image-of-God.html)

Answer (score 30):

Although [Etymonline lists pregnant as "taboo" until 1950](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pregnant#etymonline_v_19407), the OED doesn't make any such claim and [lists many uses dating from 1425](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150085?rskey=P7LRKp&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid). This includes many medical uses of the word, but also includes notable literary uses:

> *1667   Milton Paradise Lost ii. 779*   My womb ***Pregnant*** by thee, and now excessive grown Prodigious motion felt.
>
> *1914   T. S. Eliot Let. 31 Dec. (1988) 74*   I hate university towns and university people, who are the same everywhere, with ***pregnant*** wives, sprawling children,..and hideous pictures on the wall.

If the word was taboo, Milton and Eliot didn't seem to think so.

On the other hand, [Google NGrams shows that the usage of "pregnant" did increase after 1950](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pregnant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpregnant%3B%2Cc0):

[image: google ngrams of pregnant]

This seems to indicate that, while the word "pregnant" wasn't strictly taboo in the way that profanity is, it may have been disfavored.

*Note: the OED link may not work unless you have access through an academic institution.*

Comment: Interesting, but could it be that the term became sort of taboo during Victorian Era?

Comment: @user240918 Possibly, but the ngrams don't show that to the case; there is no significant drop between 1837 & 1901. OED has citations from 1881 and 1899.

Comment: Thank  you. A pet peeve just means she doesn't like it.  Please note that before the Victorian period, the English were not so dainty. Think of ribald Restoration Comedy.

Comment: Milton may have used it, but the everyday expression in his time was 'with child'. Euphemisms such as 'in the family way' and 'in an interesting condition' were used in the Victorian era. I'm not old enough to know  what more recent terms were preferred before 1950, but possibly 'expecting [a baby]'?

Comment: Honestly the usage you cite by Eliot is pretty pejorative, in parallel with the negative-sounding terms "sprawling" and "hideous." I would call that evidence in favor of it being a vulgar or taboo term.

Comment: @qdread negative-sounding =/= taboo. For example, "m-therf-cker" is taboo; "jerk" is negative. The Queen might not wish to use either term, but that doesn't make it "taboo".

Comment: @MarkBeadles: negative-sounding ≠ taboo, indeed, but the suggested negative connotations do fit with the idea that it wasn’t neutral and polite in the way it is today, and certainly fit with why the Queen would have taken issue with it.

Comment: @MarkBeadles How dare you.

Comment: The use of the word 'pregnant' isn't necessarily referring to a woman with child. A pregnant pause or a thunder cloud pregnant with the promise of rain would both be valid uses that would turn up in your google ngram so, unfortunately, it doesn't show us anything definitive.

Comment: @qdread I agree, and also in the Milton quote, the word is also used pejoratively, describing the product of rape. If you read the surrounding passage, it's quite dark. Simply finding that a word was used by someone isn't enough to mean that word is acceptable for use in polite society.

Comment: @LioElbammalf However, that poetic use of "pregnant" sounds pretty dated to my ears, and I would be willing to accept that the majority of the increase is due to the "human child" meaning, rather than the poetic one, which is probably on the decline, at least in AmE.

Answer (score 26):

I *suspect* that "pregnant" was associated with animals, which is why the Queen might find it distasteful to use for people (even more so for royals!). *This answer is a work in progress.*

### English

See [the OED entry for "pregnant"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150085?rskey=P7LRKp&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (emphasis mine):

> Etymology: < Middle French pregnant with child, pregnant (**especially of an animal**) (13th cent. in Old French; for earlier forms see note below; French prégnant ; now arch.), (of a word) full of meaning (a1585) and its etymon classical Latin praegnant-, praegnāns with child, pregnant, swollen, (as noun) pregnant woman, ...

I'm having trouble finding definitive statements to this effect, but see also [the entry](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/pregnant) for "pregnant" in the 1828 Webster's Dictionary, especially sense (1):

> **Pregnant**
>
> **PREG'NANT**, adjective [Latin proegnans; supposed to be compounded of proe, before, and geno; Gr. to beget.]
>
> 1. Being with young, as a female; breeding; teeming.
> 2. Fruitful; fertile; impregnating; as pregnant streams

It makes no reference to *human* women, and "with young, as a female; breeding; teeming" does not strike me as phrases that would have been used for humans in the early 19th century.

Also compare the [2007 OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150085?rskey=P7LRKp&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) for the "with child" meaning (why it's so far down the page I don't understand) ...

> II.3.a. Of a woman or other female mammal: having offspring developing in the uterus. †Also of the womb (obsolete). Frequently with with (the offspring), by (the male parent).

... with the [1989 definition](http://www.oed.com/oed2/00187055), which *does not* reference women:

> I. 1. That has conceived in the womb; with child or with young; gravid. Const. with, of (the offspring), by (the male parent).

Note that although the OED 2nd edition was published in 1989, the entry itself may have been written many years earlier (I could not find a date). If anyone has access to the 1st edition, I'd love to see it.

Importantly, the OED felt it necessary to add "**of a woman**" between 1989 and 2007.

However, this is definitely not universal. *[The concise Oxford dictionary of current English](https://archive.org/details/con00ciseoxforddicfowlrich/page/n3)* (1919) allows the usage for humans:

> **pregnant** a. (Of woman or female animal) with child, gravid ...

### Suggestions from other languages

As [Sara Costa](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14048/sara-costa) points out, the Portuguese word *[prenha](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prenhe#Portuguese)* - which is related to English "pregnant" - is used exclusively for animals (Wiktionary notes it as "derogatory" when used for women).

> From Old Portuguese prenne (“pregnant”), from Vulgar Latin *praegnis (“pregnant”), from Latin praegnās (“pregnant”).
>
> prenhe m, f (plural prenhes, comparable)
>
> pregnant (of an animal)
>
> (derogatory) pregnant (of a person)

This distinction is also present in [French](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/pregnant), where *[enceinte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enceinte#French)*, from Latin [*incinctus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incinctus#Latin) is used for people (this is the word Lucy had to use back in the 60s), and *[plein(e)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plein#French)* is used for animals, although *plein(e)* doesn't share a root with English "pregnant."

German, although not sharing the Latinate roots, [does distinguish](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-german/pregnant) between human and animal pregnancies.

Comment: The Portuguese word derived from the same root, 'prenha', is exclusively used for animals. I had once wondered why the English doesn't dave a word for pregnant animals different from the word for pregnant women.

Comment: To add to your interesting reasearch about other languages, also the related Italian term ***pregno/a*** is used to refer to animals and would be considered disrespectful and offensive if used to refer to a woman. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pregno/.

Comment: But if the case is, as you suggest, that the term was originally used to refer to animals, I really wonder what may have  happened around the ‘50s to make the term acceptable for human beings.

Comment: @user240918 I'd be really interested to find out! There's not a lot on the usage of this word (I would hazard a guess male lexicographers weren't excited about documenting female bodily functions)

Comment: Weird. I'd expect "gravid" exactly for an animal --- the only times I've come across it was in (old) specimen descriptions, i.e., the dead animals preserved from some expedition: NEVER "pregnant" there. And e.g. modern field biologists who I've sent photos of reptiles to ask what species they were as I couldn't get around the variable skin patterns --- they determined them all as unusual (or conversely, typical-of-a-small-region) patterns for common species; there they also added "gravid female" occasionally (which explained the different-looking proportions, that had made me doubt species).

Comment: @user3445853 I think "gravid" is pretty restricted to animals, but I think it's pretty technical. Besides, it's possible to have two words for "pregnant (animal)"

Comment: @user3445853: curiously, 'grávida' is the appropriate term for a pregnant woman in Portuguese. How odd that words with the same root end up with opposite usages in different languages.

Answer (score 19):

I don't have more to go on other then what I was taught, so I'm sorry for the lack of reference, but here we go anyway.

Pregnant is a medical condition. It is a state, with "treatments" and so on. You get there by having sex. You stop being pregnant by giving birth (or other outcomes). It's is an exact state relating to ones health. To say Sue is pregnant, is to say that Sue engaged in sex, the man orgasmed, she was fertile, "they" conceived, and now Sue in the process of gestation. Sue will one day spread her legs expose her vagina, and excrete a child.

Medical conditions like that are private and should not be discussed openly in public.

Saying that Sue is "in the family way" is very different. That means that Sue is buying kid clothes, decorating rooms, finding a sitter, saving money, planning for a college fund, picking out a doctor - and yes, somewhere in there, she probably has to get pregnant, but that's not important. What's important is Sue is making "motherly decisions". This is a vague term that can mean many different things. So it's "safer" to talk about.

Talking about pregnancy might as well be talking about sex and childbirth. Talking about a new expected family member leave room to be talking about pink or blue curtains.

Furthermore, with pregnancy in general, there is a very strong "don't jinx it" vibe.  Things like not naming a child until after birth, not knowing the gender, not announcing until later on, etc all help keep the word "pregnancy" a bit more vulgar then the alternatives. It's OK to talk about having children so long as your not talking about a specific person or process.

Lastly, and most odd, is the carry over stigma of being pregnant. Though I will not understand it, never is a woman treated less like a woman then when she is doing the most womanly thing possible. This has a long history of being true. So if you can talk about raising children without discussing the "weakness" of being pregnant....

Comment: The "don't jinx it" vibe is completely rational.  A large number of pregnancies do not result in a happy outcome for the parents, and the hardcore vulnerability of such couples is a thing not to present publicly.

Comment: Agreed with this answer. My guess is that _pregnancy_ relates verbally to impregnation, the sexual act, which is the taboo.

Comment: -1. I find your description of childbirth in appallingly bad taste, and your overall answer appears biased towards a particularly *traditional* social paradigm. This is in no way the kind of *authoritative* answer I'd expect on this site; it seems rather to be an extended personal commentary. PS plenty of women achieve pregnancy without sex, and your statement "never is a woman treated less like a woman then  [sic] when she is doing the most womanly thing possible" is simply wrong in *so many* ways.

Comment: Chappo, that is the very reason the word pregnancy ends up being Taboo as in the OP. It's also why a 92-year-old royal QUEEN that has lived from 1926 may find it vulgar. Let's not forget that during that time, she has seen an era where women were less than males, Pregnant women, in particular, were treated pretty oddly by today's standards. For example, they were not allowed to watch sports, reading was forbidden, travel was discouraged, breastfeeding was discouraged or outright forbidden, exercise was forbidden and they were encouraged to stay bedridden, lifting one's hands above your head

Comment: was not allowed, and the like. And that's for general women. A Queen, who, at the time, their cheif duty was still preceived to be to pruduce heirs, probably had it much worse.  The answer is not a commentary on how I personally feel, but you can not measuer history with today's yard stick.

Comment: as for "never is a woman treated less like a woman then when she is doing the most womanly thing possible. " I will admit that is an opinion, but no an uninformed one. Pregnant women giving birth are treated more like cattle than people in a modern hospital. And that certainly is not new. it wasn't until the 50s that women given birth were even considered. Until the 70s women given birth didn't even have to give consent to treatment. In the 30s and 40s, Women giving birth were treated as mental patients, straight jackets and all. Even today, the process is less human then most ppl are aware.

Answer (score 8):

Other answers have focused on the "vulgar" part. You also asked for ways of expressing the condition in other ways.

- [she is expecting (#5)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expect) (this was the one I would have expected in an official article)
- [she is in the family way](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/200700.html) (interesting discussion here about this use having become derogatory, which confirms an impression I had which caused me to be surprised when I read that that was the term chosen officially)
- [she is with child](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-with-child)